# how to revoke privileges for a MySQL user

Tags: mysql

There is a MySQL user with database level privileges, as shown in the screen shot below.  However, when an attempt is made to revoke privileges for this user, an error 1141 is the result.  Why is this error being generated?  How can the privileges be revoked?

I entered `show grants for 'api_user'@'localhost';` and got the ERROR 1141 message.
[image]

**Edit:**
Here I entered `REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES FROM 'api_user'@'localhost';` and got a syntax error message.
[image]

Comment: paste text not screenshots.

Comment: What happens if you don't put `GRANT OPTION` in the `REVOKE` command?

Comment: @Barmar A different error is displayed that refers to syntax.  See edit to original post for what was entered and the error.  Looking at the MySQL docs for the REVOKE command, maybe it doesn't like the fact the `, GRANT OPTION` is missing...?

Comment: Images of code and error messages are not useful. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why they should be avoided. Code (including SQL) is written in text, and can be copied and pasted directly into your post. Please [edit] to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the user only has grants on a single database, I think you need to specify that database in the `REVOKE` command:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON api_example.* FROM api_user@localhost;
```

If that doesn't work, try dropping the user:

```
DROP USER api_user@localhost;
```

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-user.html):

> The `DROP USER` statement removes one or more MySQL accounts and their privileges. It removes privilege rows for the account from all grant tables.

Comment: I tried the code you provided and here is the result: `ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'api_user' on host 'localhost'.`.

Comment: If all else fails, you could use `DROP USER api_user@localhost`

Comment: Ah.  Does `DROP USER` automatically clean up/remove any privileges that exist in MySQL for that user?

Comment: Yes, see the documentation I quoted above.

Answer (score 0):

If the grant tables hold privilege rows that contain mixed-case database or table names and the lower_case_table_names system variable is set to a nonzero value, REVOKE cannot be used to revoke these privileges. It will be necessary to manipulate the grant tables directly. (GRANT will not create such rows when lower_case_table_names is set, but such rows might have been created prior to setting the variable.)
[MySQL Revoke LowerCase](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/revoke.html)

Comment: All of the database names and user names are lower case.  I do not see any mixed-case database or table names.